# Accelerometer direction detection

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

I have the following code

```
playerPosition.x += acceleration.x * 10;
playerPosition.y += acceleration.y * 20;
```

acceleration currently works, I would like to detect if the player should move backwards(y decreasing) and if so change it to

```
playerPosition.y += acceleration.y * 10;
```

How does one detect if acceleration from the accelerometer is negative?

How does one retrieve the direction of the movement? left right etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just compare the acceleration with 0

```
acceleration.y < 0.0
```

or

```
acceleration.y > 0.0
```

There is a free app iSimulate where you can see what values accelerometer outputs.